# JUpload applet and PHP sample error "unable to move uploaded file"

Tags: php, file-upload, applet, jupload

I'm experimenting with the JUpload applet and PHP sample to upload very large files to a website. However, for any large files, the uploads are failing with a strange error `Unable to move uploaded file (from  to /var/tmp...`, where the from file name is blank. Any ideas what the cause is?

Thanks!

Comment: After editing jupload.php to dump the file variable, it seems the reason is the chunk file being uploaded is too big for the limit in php.ini. So either changing the max file size in php.ini or the  'maxChunkSize' in the $appletParameters variable resolves the issue.

Comment: Please use back ticks to format code/errors/etc